# [VOLTTRON]: bootstrap.py failed to run virtual environment

Tags: raspberry-pi, volttron

I am unable to create a virtual environment to run **VOLTTRON**. Every time I run `bootstrap.py`, I get an error saying `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`. The screenshot is attached below.

Is this the issue with the **VOLTTRON** version or do I need additional dependencies to run the file?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the branch and machine specifications that you are attempting to run this on.

Comment: I am trying to run the develop branch into raspberry pi 3. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a pull request that was just merged into master that fixes this issue on raspberry pis.  The ssl context is only required with rabbitmq and/or web services enabled.  Please update to the latest version of master and try again.